# Двоеточие при разрыве прямой речи словами автора

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, двоеточие, абзац

Возник у нас с автором спор на тему двоеточия в прямой речи.

> — Отлично. — Парень кивнул, даже не взглянув на девушек и продолжая
>   изучать какие-то документы. Спустя мгновение он поднял взгляд на
>   сотрудниц и обратился к **Еве: — Кстати**, Сомова, отчет готов?

Я говорю, что если слова автора завершаются двоеточием, то прямую речь следует перенести на новую строку. Автор не согласен и утверждает, что это правило не работает, если слова автора разрывают прямую речь. Рассудите нас, пожалуйста.

Comment: "Спор на тему двоеточия"(?!) Вопрос, ставить двоеточие или нет? А то мы тут обсуждаем другую тему: что переносить на другую строку.

Comment: Мне кажется, что для этого вопроса можно создать новую метку - _абзац_ (вопросы с похожей тематикой встречаются, а метка отсутствует). Каково Ваше мнение? Я бы добавила.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Я поддерживаю. Предложите на Мете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Эту тему регулирует правило Розенталя:**  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161#pp161

4. Если между двумя репликами одного и того же говорящего лица находится текст от автора, то ни этот текст, ни последующая прямая речь в отдельные абзацы обычно не выделяются:

— Не получается  у меня с проводом, — ответил мастер. Он немного подумал и добавил: — Придётся всё делать заново.

Но если в тексте от автора **описывается действие говорящего лица**, то и авторский текст, и последующая прямая речь **выделяются в абзацы:**

— Формула эта может иметь и другой вид, — пояснил профессор.

Он неторопливо подошёл к доске, взял мел и написал что-то новое для нас.

— Вот это и есть другой вариант, — сказал он.

В приведенном тексте описывается действие, **поэтому надо применить вторую часть правила.** Возможно, это будет выглядеть так:

— Отлично.

Парень кивнул, даже не взглянув на девушек и продолжая изучать какие-то документы. Спустя мгновение он поднял взгляд на сотрудниц и обратился к Еве:

— Кстати, Сомова, отчет готов?

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, почему "подумал и добавил" - не действие?

Comment: Это слова со значением речи, мысли, в данной теме они противопоставлены  другим действиям,  не связанным напрямую с прямой речью (кивнул, продолжал изучать).

Comment: Спасибо, запомню

Comment: А как тут понять, кто сказал: "Отлично"?

Comment: Я думаю, что парень. А Вы как считаете?

Comment: Если *парень* идет с абзаца, то, судя по структуре, кто-то сказал "Отлично", на это парень кивнул.

Comment: Если читать всю книгу, то будет ясно, кто говорит и кто кивает.

Answer (score 0):

Существует лишь два способа открывать прямую речь — с абзаца посредством тире и кавычками. Приведённый фрагмент недопустимо использует оба. Надо определиться!

Способ 1

— Отлично. — Парень кивнул, даже не взглянув на девушек и продолжая изучать какие-то документы. Спустя мгновение он поднял взгляд на сотрудниц и обратился к Еве:

— Кстати, Сомова, отчет готов?

Способ 2

«Отлично», — парень кивнул, даже не взглянув на девушек и продолжая изучать какие-то документы. Спустя мгновение он поднял взгляд на сотрудниц и обратился к Еве: «Кстати, Сомова, отчет готов?»

В вашем с автором случае спор может решить замена двоеточия запятой.

— Отлично, — парень кивнул, даже не взглянув на девушек и продолжая изучать какие-то документы. Спустя мгновение он поднял взгляд на сотрудниц и обратился к Еве, — Кстати, Сомова, отчет готов?

Comment: *...и обратился к Еве, — Кстати, Сомова, отчет готов?* - вот этой запятой перед тире никак не д***о***лжно быть.

Comment: @Galina Avanesova  Куда же Вы пропали?  Мы уже соскучились без Ваших вопросов и ответов. Вас здесь не хватает.

Comment: "— Отлично. — Парень кивнул". Есть такое правило, которое разрешает начинать слова автора, идущие после прямой речи, с заглавной буквы?

Comment: Конечно нельзя. Но если хочется, то можно: Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы: — Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, первое предложение в словах автора связано с первой частью прямой речи, а второе — со второй. Поэтому мой вариант таков.

**— Отлично, — парень кивнул, продолжая изучать какие-то документы и даже не взглянув на девушек.**

**Спустя мгновение он поднял взгляд на сотрудниц и обратился к Еве:**

**— Кстати, Сомова, отчет готов?**

Примечание 1. Не вижу причин начинать слова автора, идущие после прямой речи, с прописной буквы.

Примечание 2. Я переставил местами  деепричастные обороты, такой порядок логичнее.

Дополнение. Нашел правило у Розенталя:

> Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы:
>   *— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.* ([§ 49. Прямая речь перед словами автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154))

Это позволяет начать слова автора с прописной буквы:

**— Отлично. — Парень кивнул, продолжая изучать какие-то документы и даже не взглянув на девушек.**

**Спустя мгновение он поднял взгляд на сотрудниц и обратился к Еве:**

**— Кстати, Сомова, отчет готов?**

Примечание. Мое предпочтение на стороне первого варианта (слова автора со срочной). Я считаю, что *кивнул* относится к прямой речи (парень кивнул и сказал: "Отлично"). Второй вариант означает, что парень сначала сказал "Отлично", а потом кивнул — вряд ли так бывает.

[1](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154)http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154

Comment: Вряд ли автор согласится с вашим вариантом, ведь он не просил его редактировать. У него свой стиль, своя манера письма, своё в видение данной ситуации, а Вы всё исправили.

Comment: @Jasmin Вы находите, что начинать слова автора, идущие после прямой речи, с прописной — допустимо?

Comment: – Да, это заметно. – Павел Петрович начал, не торопясь, намазывать масло на хлеб. – Долго он у нас прогостит?

Comment: Но вот: "Слова автора во всех случаях начинаются с маленькой буквы" (Полный справочник школьника, 5—11 классы)

Comment: Также на Грамоте: http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_192

Comment: @Jasmin Полагаю, у Тургенева — то, что называется "авторский текст", а не слова автора, но тогда по какому праву у него стоит тире после прамой речи?

Comment: Зачем....Затем, что ветру и орлу И сердцу девы нет  закона. А если серьезно, то всё правильно у Тургенева. А вот это Булгаков (оформление в абзац): – Слушай, это верно?
Шервинский стал бурым.
– Гм, даже странно.

Comment: Полный справочник для школьника и даже Грамота не могут отрегулировать все варианты оформления прямой речи. Обобщать они не умеют, пользуются ограниченным и отчасти устаревшим материалом. В современной литературе много того, что еще не зафиксировано правилами.

Comment: @Jasmin Я задал об этом отдельный вопрос. Ваш ответ будет там уместен.

Comment: Непременно, но  позже, когда появится время.  Также надеюсь на активность других участников.